# ActionBarSherlock: Button not appearing on Android 2

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock because I want to create a unified for many devices. I want to support devices down to some Android 2 version. For testing I have a

-LG Nexus 4 --running Android 4.2.2
-Samsung Galaxy Ace --running Android 2.3.3

To begin using the abs I fetched some sample code from the samples shipped with abs. Mainly I used the ActionItems.java example-file. I used only one delete-button. I copied the appropriate drawables to the res folders (see [Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1773770/abs_resFolder.png)). (I created the ldpi-version with 36x36pixels- saved with alpha channel)

The problem is that the delete icon won't appear on the Samsung Ace with Android 2.3.3.
See [Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1773770/abs_comparison.jpg)
What is wrong with my code? 
Here's my code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements Observer {

public static int THEME = R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fillTableViewWithEvents();

    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);

    setTitle(...);
}





    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar
    boolean isLight = THEME == R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;

    MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    menu.add("Delete")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_action_delete : R.drawable.ic_action_delete)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return true;
}
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml I added this line (replacing the old @style statement

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
```

Comment: use .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

Comment: use `MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS` to show always a button in ABS

Comment: It probably has not enough space. Try pressing menu button on your phone and see if it will show on the bottom of the screen in menu. And also try with removing `MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT`.

Comment: Issue is solved! I missed it to modify the import statements. After replacing `import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;` with `import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;` the button is showing up!  @MichałZ.: Thanks for the hint with the menu-button. Pressing it caused a exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.MenuItem.setShowAsAction` which leaded me to the import statements. Thanks guys!